# ngmodel is not working with ngrepeat in android

Tags: android, angularjs

input box not taking any field while it is surrounded in ngrepeat . in browser it is working perfectly but giving error while running in android as web view .

```
 <div ng-repeat="teleOrderDetail in teleOrderDetails">          
   <table style="text-align:center;font-size:13px;width:98%;height:9%;">
      <tr>
         <td style="color:grey;width:33.34%;"><input type="tel" name="quantity" ng-model="teleOrderDetail.quantity"  class="inputtd"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

input type 'tel' appears to only be supported by Safari. This might be your problem with it displaying properly. Could you perhaps provide a little more information about the error if this isn't the problem?

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: input filed is not editable .so not able to add any value to input box . it is because  while using both ngrepeat and ngmodel .